# In Project Hail Mary, How did the medical robot solve the zero-G bone deterioration problem?

Tags: project-hail-mary

In [*Project Hail Mary* by Andy Weir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Hail_Mary), the challenges of space travel are addressed in two discussions so far, (`p.108-111`) sanity/ comas/ crew quality and (`p.256`) medical armature ("robot") for the crew that possess long-term coma resistance.

A recent [piece about lettuce](https://astronomy.com/news/2022/03/genetically-modified-space-grown-lettuce-could-save-astronauts-bones) engineered to deliver **parathyroid hormone** to astronauts to promote bone health made me wonder how the *Hail Mary* crew solved it.

There isn't any mention of bone issues when Grace wakes from his coma, on the contrary, he marvels at his excellent physical condition (`p.12, 27`):

> Why am I so weak when I have these well-toned muscles? ...I should be a withered, spindly mess right now, not beach-bod buff.

> And we were kept fit. Electrodes all over our bodies to stimulate muscle movement. Lots of exercise.

Comment: Lots of exercise is the standard way that astronauts combat bone loss. With electrical stimulation I guess his muscles were being exercised while he was in the coma

Comment: Isnt bone density loss normally due to microgravity, and the Hail Mary was not in microgravity for its entire journey there?  The spin system was for when it got to its destination and was no longer accelerating or decelerating, so there would always have been “gravity” acting on the crew?

Comment: You're right. It makes sense now. He does work out the math and says the ship maintained 1.5 g's of acceleration. I even remember thinking how he says he could have strapped everything down since he knew when the ship was going to slow down and the lab equipment floats.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been answered in the comments, but deserves a permanent response.

The medical robot does not have to deal with bone deterioration in micro-gravity because the Hail Mary is under constant acceleration at 1.5g.

Half of the first chapter is devoted to the main character, who at the time does not recall his own name, working out that his current location has a gravity of 1.5g after finding the rate of falling objects unsettling.

Later in the book (Chapter 25), the journey times are laid out showing the ship constantly accelerating and decelerating in order to minimise the mission time and maximise the chance of saving the world.

> The trip from Earth to Tau Ceti took three years and nine months. (Hail Mary Timeframe) And it was done by accelerating constantly at 1.5gs the entire time.